# how to execute all the invoke top level maven target in jenkins and execute remaining build steps only if maven target are successful

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, junit, continuous-integration

I have a Continuous integration setup using jenkins. I need to run Junit test cases and selenium test cases and commit the jar files in svn, only if all the junit and selenium scripts are passed.

Junit and selenium test cases are separate maven projects so i have used two **invoke top level maven targets** (One for selenium and other for Junit). I came across following issues,

1. Selenium scripts will be executed first and if any of the selenium test cases are failed, the jenkins build is marked as Failed and it will start to execute the post-build actions skipping all the build steps including junit. I want to run the Junit test cases also even if selenium scripts are failed. So i have added **-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true** in maven goals to execute the junit test cases even if selenium scripts are failed. This worked perfectly as i expected and continued to execute junit test caes and the build is marked as UNSTABLE.
2. Now i got another issue, i have a build step to invoke ant at the end (To commit jars in svn only if selenium and junit are passed). After adding **-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true**, the jars are getting commited to svn even if there is any failures.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

1. The build should run both Selenium and Junit, even if there is any failure in any one of project.
2. Jars should be committed in svn only if everything is successful (This is done by using ant target, so i have placed invoke ant at the end in Build step.

Is there any other way to accomplish this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: any solution for this ?